# Transactions per second in LoadRunner/Performance Center

Tags: java, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have specified two transactions in the action as below.

```
lr.start_transaction("transaction1");
//Some transaction1 code goes here
lr.end_transaction("transaction1", lr.AUTO);

lr.start_transaction("transaction2");
//Some transaction2 code goes here
lr.end_transaction("transaction2", lr.AUTO);
```

Is it possible to have **TransactionsPerSecond(TPS)** report for the above two transactions individually? Like I have to get how many transactions per second happened for transaction1 and the same for transaction2. Can someone please shed some light on how to achieve this? Of course the number of transactions happened is anyways shown individually, but I want to get individual **TPS**.

**Note:** The reason I put both the transactions in the same action is --> output of transaction1 code is used as input for transaction2.

Answer (score 0):

Create two graphs for transactions per second.  Filter each of the graphs for just the transaction you want.  Then you will have a transaction per second graph uniquely tied to each of your transactions.

Comment: I am sorry, could you please elaborate on how to create two graphs, I know that by default it provides total transactions per second graph in the "Total Transactions Per Second" tab.

Comment: In Analysis.  Add a graph.  Pick the appropriate type.  Use the Graph filter to include just the transaction(s) you wish.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but  I am able to find only analyze option once the test run completes, when I click on analyze, it directly gives me report. I am not able to find any options to select in the way that you explained in performance center. Once I click on Runs--> Select particular test --> only analyze option is present at top. Once I click on it, it generates report.

Comment: Yes, in analysis, when the test completes.  Add a graph.  Add a transaction graph.   Then on that graph filter for just the items of your interest.